# How to record screen for browser in webdriverIO?

Tags: webdriver-io

I have been trying to record screen using different npm packages but I am unable to record the screen when the test is running on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will help:
https://github.com/praveenprasannan/wdio-video-recorder

Also you can use Selenoid (https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/): your tests will be running inside docker-containers. About video-recording:
https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/#_video_recording